# Radio button navigation from databatase

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to work out how a click a category echoed from database table using a while loop should navigate to a specific page. Whenever we select on radio button it should navigate to some URL like in the below example clicking on

```
<li class="filter-list"><input class="pixel-radio" type="radio" id="men" name="brand">
<label for="men">Men<span> (3600)</span></label>
</li>
```

should navigate to men category, and

```
<li class="filter-list"><input class="pixel-radio" type="radio" id="women" name="brand">
<label for="women">women<span> (3700)</span></label>
</li>
```

should navigate to women category.

```
<form action="" method="post">
<ul>

    <?php 
    $query = "SELECT * FROM categories ";
    $select_all_categories_query = mysqli_query($connection,$query);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select_all_categories_query)) {
    $cat_title = $row['cat_title']; 
    $cat_id = $row['cat_id'];
        echo
            "<li class='filter-list'><input class='pixel-radio' type='radio' id='$cat_id' name='category' value='$cat_title'><label for='$cat_id'>{$cat_title}</label></li>";
    }?>
```